# Multiple functions for one action?

Tags: php, file, function

I currently have this code in PHP:

```
public function newFile($folder, $file){
    fopen($folder."/".$file, 'w');
}
```

That I use like this:

```
newFile('myfolder', 'myfile.txt');
```

It works fine, but I want to know if it's possible to create a function that I can use like this:

```
newFile('myfile.txt') inFolder('myfolder');
```

How can I do this, if it's possible?

I could also use this:

```
newFile('myfile.txt')->inFolder('myfolder');
```

Comment: What are you asking? `function('param') function('param')` is not valid PHP code. What's wrong with `function('param', 'param')`?

Comment: Yes, try to express more clearly what you want to achieve...

Comment: I think you are looking for something like the named parameters idiom.

Comment: If it is important to you to be able to do this, you would be able to acheive syntax that looks like this: `newFile('myfile.txt')->inFolder('myfolder')`

Comment: @Tim how can I do that?

Comment: @Me123 Check out my answer. It does this exactly using classes.

Comment: @Me123 h2ooooooo has posted how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could possibly implement. Such technique is often used, when you need to call a lof of functions of the same object (better readability).

The point is that your functions may return the reference to the same object:

```
class Creator {
  private $file ;
  private $folder = "" ;

  public function newFile($file){
    $this->file = $file ;
    return $this ;
  }

  public function inFolder($folder){
    $this->folder = $folder ;
    return $this ;
  }

  public function create(){
    return fopen($this->folder."/".$this->file, 'w');
  }
}

$creator = new Creator();

$creator
  ->newFile("test.txt")
  ->inFolder("test")
  ->create();
```

Comment: I think this sort of thing is prettier with a helper function in the global namespace. i.e. `newFile` is a free function that returns an instance of the proxy.

Comment: This would be the route I'd have gone rather than the other version below.  This to me is more readable/maintainable. Though perhaps a hybrid of the 2 using a constructor for setting the inputs on new rather than as below setting one on construct and the other as a param to the other method

Answer (score 5):

I can see that you are trying to achieve a syntax like Objective-C and similar languages, but unfortunately, you can't. Just get used to the PHP syntax.

You could use an array to get named parameters, though:

```
function newFile($params){
    fopen($params['folder']."/".$params['file'], 'w');
}

newFile(array(
    'folder' => 'myfolder',
    'file' => 'myfile.txt'
));
```

Alternatively you could use proxies to get to a syntax like: `newFile(...)->inFolder(...)`, but that would definitely be an overkill here.

Comment: @Jeffrey how can I do newFile()->inFolder(); ?

Comment: @Me123, follow the other answers. But I highly suggest you not to do that. It's more complexity for nothing.

Comment: I agree with you on this one. Even the array trick here is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Jeffrey but I have to. I'm doing this for a client.

Comment: @Me123 Does your client *really* want to use a solution that's complex, obscure and most likely drags down more resources than a simple and elegant solution?

Comment: @Me123 I usually try explain to clients calmly why something is a bad solution. Usually they end up agreeing with me.

Comment: I tend to tell them they're morons :)

Comment: @Tim Pretty much the same that I do. I tell clients *why* something is bad, what we *should* do instead, but end up saying "however, it's your choice. If you want to do it this way, we can". That way, you give them a final chance if they *really* want to use the worse solution.

Comment: @h2ooooooo well technically I usually explain it to my boss, since he has more contact with the clients and has a silver tongue.

Comment: @Tim okay I'll tell him.

Comment: @Tim Usually my "client" *is* my boss :)

Answer (score 1):

As for the solution of `newFile('file')->inFolder('folder')` it is possible, but it'd be definite overkill in this situation. Here's an example how to do it, though:

```
<?php
    class File_To_Be_Created {
        private $file;

        public function __construct($file) {
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        public function inFolder($folder) {
            $handle = fopen($folder . '/' . $this->file, 'w');

            if ($handle !== false) {
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }

    function newFile($file) {
        return new File_To_Be_Created($file);
    }

    newFile('myfile.txt')->inFolder('myfolder');
?>
```